# Error al simular una variable de sesión con jest en node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, express-session, jest

estoy aprendiendo a hacer tests de integración continua en node con jest, pero al mandar un parámetro simulando una variable de sesión no me funciona el test, y me da un error 500,
este es el código de mi test

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../routes/usuarios');


describe('Listado de usuarios', () => {
    test('Sacamos el listado con token erroneo', async(req) => {
        const response = await request(app)
            .get('/usuarios')
            .send({ token: '0000000000000000000000000000000' })
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

        expect(response.text).toBe("-5");

    });
});
```

y este el de mi usuarios.js de routes:

```
app.get("/usuarios", (req, res) => {
    const token = req.session.usuario.token;

    let usuarios = async(token) => {
        await sql.connect(config);
        let db = new sql.Request();
        db.input('token', sql.VarChar(100), token);
        let result = await db.execute('VER_LISTA_USUARIOS')
        return result.recordset;
    };

    usuarios(token).then(usuarios => {
        if (usuarios.idUsuario == -5) {
            return res.status(404).send('Error al ver los usuarios');
        } else {
            res.render("usuarios.hbs", { usuario: usuarios });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(404).send('Error al ver los usuarios');
    })

});
```

Como puedo pasarle esa variable token para hacer mis tests?? soy nuevo y todavía no tengo mucha idea, muchas gracias

Comment: 500 es un error interno... ¿qué error tienes?

Comment: Que no existe req.session.usuario.token, como podría mandar variables desde jest??